# LEGO-compatible suction cups?

Tags: 3rd-party, pneumatic

I'm looking for suction cups that are compatible with the LEGO pneumatic system.  I've seen people who have built things with them (on YouTube videos, etc), but haven't found anything on eBay or BrickLink.  Short of drilling a hole in a normal suction cup and popping a pneumatic tube into it, is there anything out there I could buy?

Comment: Check out [The Vertigo III on LEGO.com's NXTLOG](http://us.mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/Community/NXTLog/DisplayProject.aspx?id=d951c84b-8a5b-4dd6-a79f-6b37b498d202). It is probably a pretty good example of what Dave's looking for.

Comment: @PeterDC yep, that's exactly what I'm looking for! :)

Comment: That link got broken in Fall 2013 when the MINDSTORMS website updated, so here's a fixed link: http://www.us.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/community/robot?projectid=d951c84b-8a5b-4dd6-a79f-6b37b498d202

Comment: @HaydenStudios And THAT link is broken, too. Please fix it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [post about Vertigo](http://www.us.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/community/robot?projectid=d951c84b-8a5b-4dd6-a79f-6b37b498d202) (the precursor to [Rory's answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1116/56)), TrilogyGlenIvy (the creator) stated:

> Suction cup hangers were easily located in stores. Drilling a small hole and inserting a short section of copper tubing (1/8 “ or ~3 mm diameter) along with some vinyl glue produced the feet that I used.

Basically they are usually found in DIY/Home stores as metal or plastic hooks wrapped around a transparent suction cup so you can easily affix them to tiles or windows.

There is also a picture showing three variants that were tried, with the preferred option being those in the bottom left I think:

[image: Suction Cup Variants]

Depending on the weight of the model you've got you may also need to invest in some additional custom air bellows:

> An internet search finally pointed to a “Climb@tron Vertibug” toy that contained two air bellows (~23 mm in diameter). I bought one of the toys, removed the air bellows, and designed a “worm gear slider” system using NXT parts to stretch and compress them. The vacuum system was then installed in Vertigo and has worked reasonably well.

Comment: AHA! I should've kept looking a little bit longer then.  This is pretty much what I was looking for.  Thanks! :)

Comment: @DaveDeLong No probs.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely [Vertigo III](http://www.us.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/community/robot?projectid=d951c84b-8a5b-4dd6-a79f-6b37b498d202) - superb build project

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question specifically asked "is there anything out there I could buy?". Unless the suction cups for the Vertigo III are for sale, this is not a valid answer. Sorry if I'm sounding harsh, but this is *not* one of the possible right answers.

Comment: It looks like it is for sale under one of the Education links - the 9641 Pneumatic add-on set

Comment: @RoryAlsop: According to Peeron, 9641 doesn't include the suction cups. http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/9641-1

Comment: Ahhh - I take it all back then. Sorry for getting your hopes up.